# Notepad++ Search for and replace Underscore Characters in "GUIDs"

Tags: regex, notepad++, guid

A colleague has written some C# code that outputs GUIDs to a CSV file. The code has been running for a while but it has been discovered that the GUIDs contain underscore characters, instead of hyphens :-(

There are several files which have been produced already and rather than regenerate these, I'm thinking that we could use the Search and Replace facility in Notepad++ to search across the files for "GUIDs" in this format:
`{89695C16_C0FF_4E7C_9BB2_8B50FAC9D371}`
and replace it with a properly formatted GUID like this:
`{89695C16-C0FF-4E7C-9BB2-8B50FAC9D371}`.

I have a RegEx to find the offending GUIDs (probably not very efficient):

```
(([A-Z]|[0-9]){8}_)(([A-Z]|[0-9]){4})_(([A-Z]|[0-9]){4})_(([A-Z]|[0-9]){4}_(([A-Z]|[0-9]){12}))
```

but I don't know what RegEx to use to replace the underscores with. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried: Find: `_` Replace: `-`

Comment: How many files are we talking about? A dozen? Dozens? Hundreds?

Comment: Straightforward Find & Replace won't work because the CSVs contain other data as well as the GUIDs which may have underscores chars in it.

Comment: So far there are around 40 CSV files. Many more will be produced but the code has been fixed now

Comment: I have a RegEx to find the offending GUIDs (probably not very efficient):(([A-Z]|[0-9]){8}_)(([A-Z]|[0-9]){4})_(([A-Z]|[0-9]){4})_(([A-Z]|[0-9]){4}_(([A-Z]|[0-9]){12})) but I don't know what RegEx to use to replace the underscores with?

Comment: You can simplify that pattern like `([A-Z0-9]{8})_([A-Z0-9]{4})_([A-Z0-9]{4})_([A-Z0-9]{4})_([A-Z0-9]{12})` and then use the 5 capture groups in the replacement like `$1-$2-$3-$4-$5` See https://regex101.com/r/EKpcq1/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird: thanks very much - that works perfectly and more importantly, I've learned something!

Comment: If the only stuff in your content that starts with `{` are these GUIDs, it might be sufficient to use eg [`(?:\G(?!^)|{)[A-Z\d]+\K_`](https://regex101.com/r/aX8P3r/1) (*replace all* with hyphen)

Answer (score 4):

You can match the pattern with 5 capture groups where you would match the underscores in between.

Then you can use the capture groups in the replacement with `$1-$2-$3-$4-$5`

```
{\K([A-Z0-9]{8})_([A-Z0-9]{4})_([A-Z0-9]{4})_([A-Z0-9]{4})_([A-Z0-9]{12})(?=})
```

- `{` Match `{`
- `\K` Clear the match buffer (forget what is matched so far)
- `([A-Z0-9]{8})_` Capture **group 1**, match 8 times a char A-Z0-9
- `([A-Z0-9]{4})_` Capture 4 times a char A-Z0-9 in **group 2**
- `([A-Z0-9]{4})_` Same for **group 3**
- `([A-Z0-9]{4})_` Same for **group 4**
- `([A-Z0-9]{12})` Capture 12 times a char A-Z0-9 in **group 5**
- `(?=})` Positive lookahead, assert `}` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ADAmDy/1)

If the pattern should also match without matching the curly's `{` and `}` you can append word boundaries

```
\b([A-Z0-9]{8})_([A-Z0-9]{4})_([A-Z0-9]{4})_([A-Z0-9]{4})_([A-Z0-9]{12})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AJqFXT/1)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution:

**Find What**: `(?:\G(?!\A)|{(?=[a-f\d]{8}(?:_[a-f\d]{4}){4}[a-f\d]{8}\}))[a-f\d]*\K_`
**Replace with**: `-`
**Match case**: OFF

See the settings and demo:

[image]

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/eaHj4c/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|{(?=[a-f\d]{8}(?:_[a-f\d]{4}){4}[a-f\d]{8}\}))` - either the end of the previous match or a `{` char immediately followed with eight alphanumeric chars, four repetitions of an underscore and then four alphanumeric chars and then eight alphanumeric chars and a `}` char
- `[a-f\d]*` - zero or more alphanumeric chars
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `_` - an underscore.